# Prove the Hadamard product representation

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, kronecker-product, hadamard-product

Let $A$ and $B$ be $m \times n$ matrices with low-rank structures:
$$
A = U_{A}\Sigma_{A}V_{A}^{T},\quad B= U_{B}\Sigma_{B}V_{B}^{T},
$$

Prove that Hadamard product $A\circ B$ admits the following representation
$$
A\circ B = (U_{A}^T\odot U_{B}^T)^T (\Sigma_{A}\otimes\Sigma_{B})(V_{A}^{T}\odot V_{B}^{T}),
$$
where $\odot$ represents the Khatri-Rao product, and $\otimes$ the Kronecker product.

Comment: [The Khatri-Rao product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Khatri%E2%80%93Rao_product), for those unfamiliar

Comment: This is an interesting problem, where did you encounter it?  Also, could you clarify how exactly $U_A$ is meant to be partitioned for the Khatri-Rao product?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $U_{a}$ is the matrix of left singular vectors of A.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916069

Answer (score 3):

We will use the following properties and definitions:
\begin{align}
    (A\odot^T B)(C\odot D) = (AC)\circ(BD),\label{eq:khr-had}\\
    (A\otimes B)(C\odot D) = (AC)\odot(BD),\label{eq:khr-kro}
\end{align}
It is easy to prove that Hadamard product of A and B admits the following representation:
\begin{align}
    A \circ B 
    &= (U_{A}\Sigma_{A}V_{A}^{T})\circ(U_{B}\Sigma_{B}V_{B}^{T})\nonumber\\
    &= (U_{A}^T\odot U_{B}^T)^T (\Sigma_{A}V_{A}^{T}\odot \Sigma_{B}V_{B}^{T})\nonumber\\
    &=(U_{A}^T\odot U_{B}^T)^T (\Sigma_{A}\otimes\Sigma_{B})(V_{A}^{T}\odot V_{B}^{T})\label{eq:repres}
\end{align}
where $\odot$ represents the Khatri-Rao product, and $\otimes$ the Kronecker product.