# Khatri-Rao product as a matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

Assume the following matrices are defined

$$
\mathbf{A}\in\mathbf{R}^{N\times P},\ \mathbf{B}\in\mathbf{R}^{M\times P},\ \mathbf{q}\in \mathbf{R}^{P\times 1},\ \mathbf{Q}^{P\times P}=\text{diag}(\mathbf{q})
$$

where $\mathbf{R}$ denotes the set of real numbers. 
Through different numerical examples, I can verify that
$$
\text{vec}\{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}^T\}=(\mathbf{A}\odot\mathbf{B})\mathbf{q}
$$
where $\odot$ denotes the *[Khatri-Rao product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1916069/khatri-rao-product-example)*, vec denotes the [vectorization operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and $^T$ is the transpose operation. I was wondering if there is a mathematical proof for the above equation.

Comment: Combining the expansion the Khatri-Rao product in terms of 
all-ones vectors $\left({\tt1_N}\in{\mathbb R}^{N\times 1}\right)$ 
and the Hadamard $(\circ)$ and Kronecker $(\otimes)$ products
$$\eqalign{
A\odot B &= (A\otimes{\tt1_M})\circ({\tt1_N}\otimes B) \\
}$$
with a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993406/) answers the current question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=[\mathbf{b}_1\dots \mathbf{b}_P]$ and $A=[\mathbf{a}_1\dots \mathbf{a}_P]$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{vec}\{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{A}^T\}
&=
\sum_{p=1}^Pq_p\text{vec}(\mathbf{b}_p\mathbf{a}_p')
\\&=
\sum_{p=1}^Pq_p \mathbf{a}_p \otimes\mathbf{b}_p
\\&=
[\mathbf{a}_1 \otimes\mathbf{b}_1 \dots \mathbf{a}_P \otimes\mathbf{b}_P]
\begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ \vdots \\ q_P\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
(\mathbf{A}\odot\mathbf{B})\mathbf{q}.
\end{aligned}
$$